# search for what is in file 1 in file 2 and output file 2 column

Tags: shell-script

Find for what is in file1 in file2 and the output should contain what is in file2, but the second column.

File1:

```
DataCreditoEAR.ear
PostSale.ear
```

File2:

```
DataCreditoEAR.ear      /usr/DataCreditoEAR
DatacreditTableAdministrator.ear        /usr/DatacreditTableAdministrator
PostSale.ear    /usr/PostSale
```

Output:

```
/usr/DataCreditoEAR
/usr/PostSale
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest/simplest way is to use `grep` to do the pattern matching, and then `awk` to extract the second field.

```
grep -f File1 File2 | awk '{print $2}'
```

If File1 contains fixed-strings rather than regexp patterns, use grep's `-F` aka `--fixed-strings` option:

```
grep -F -f File1 File2 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fields (columns) in File2 are delimited by tabs,

```
grep -f File1 File2 | cut -f2
```

otherwise,

```
grep -f File1 File2 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Or, entirely in awk (and independent of the flavor of the whitespace):

```
awk '!flag { a[$1]++ } flag { if (a[$1]) print $2 }' File1 flag=2 File2
```

Comment: Rather than using a flag, you can just compare the record number to the file record number to check for the first file. `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]{print $2}' File1 File2`

Comment: Yes, you ***can*** do that, and it will work correctly if the first file is non-empty.  And, yes, in this particular case, both commands will (correctly) produce no output if File1 is empty.  But the flag approach is safer in general.

Comment: join -o 2.2 <(sort instalar_componentes) <(sort deploy), I worked with this